# Recuperar valor da chave adicionada no formData no backend

Tags: node.js, formdata, multer

Galera tenho a seguinte requisição no frontend

```
  formData.append("file", this.file);
  formData.append("name", "test");

  axios
    .post(`${baseApiUrl}/exame`, formData)
```

No backend eu consigo recuperar o valor do campo "file" com essa função:

```
const upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' }).single("file")

function save(req, res) {
    upload(req, res, function (err) {
        console.log(req.file) // Acesso ao conteúdo de file
        console.log(req.name) // Undefined :(
    })
}
```

Porém minha dúvida é, como faço para recuperar o campo "name" e outros caso eu decida adicionar?

OBS: Estou chamando a função upload dessa forma pois preciso capturar os erros (caso existam) na hora de gravar o arquivo, segundo a documentação [doc multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#error-handling)

Answer (score 0):

O correto é `req.body` para pegar o conteudo de um POST, então seria isso:

```
console.log(req.body)
```

Agora se esta usando multer e na verdade deseja pegar trabalhar o upload de um unico arquivo deveria fazer algo como:

```
const upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })

app.post('/profile', upload.single('file'), function (req, res, next) {
  console.log("arquivo", req.file) is the `avatar` file
  console.log(req.body)
})
```

Isso aqui parece errado: `upload(req, res, function (err) {` e você escreveu o retorno dentro do terceiro parâmetro do objeto do mutler, quando deveria ser o terceiro parâmetro do objeto do app no método .post()

---

Se for upload múltiplo:

```
const upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })

app.post('/photos/upload', upload.array('file', 12), function (req, res, next) {
     console.log(req.files);
     console.log(req.body);
})
```

Isso supondo que você esteja usando Express

Comment: Olá guilherme, obrigado por ajudar! No caso eu usei dessa forma pois preciso capturar os erros na hora que salvar o aquivo (caso exista), como mostra [link](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#error-handling). Sobre o req.body ele sempre vem como undefined :/

Comment: @Retiorts isso não foi informado na pergunta, parecia mais um erro de digitação, isso você sempre deve explicar. Vou editar

Comment: Verdade, esqueci de mencionar. Valeu, fico no aguardo :D